# Fetch latest 100 documents

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

How can I get the latest created 100 documents? My entity consists of id, name, URL, description.
Should I add the creation date also?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add `create_date` and `modified_date`. When you query the documents, you need to order by either of the date and add limit of 100.

With `spring-data-mongodb`, something like this:

```
List<Your Entity> entity = <Your Repository>.findTop100OrderByCreateDateDesc(createDate);
```

Refer to: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 0):

The default document _id contain the creation date, you can fetch latest 100 created documents easily as follow:

```
   db.col.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(100)
```

or

```
   db.col.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(100)
```